# Drawing and going first

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In what scenarios or formats can a player draw even when they are going first?

For example: I usually play that if there are more than 2 teams (each team having 1 or more players) then the first team can draw on their first turn.

Are there other scenarios or formats that affect this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When there are more than two players/teams.

> 103.7a In a two-player game, the player who plays first skips the draw step (see rule 504, “Draw Step”) of his or her first turn.
>
> 103.7b In a Two-Headed Giant game, the team who plays first skips the draw step of their first turn.
>
> 103.7c In all other multiplayer games, no player skips the draw step of his or her first turn.